# Valor baseado em outro campo (Crystal Reports)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

Como faço para obter o `Valor Unit` da última compra no Crystal Reports numa tabela resultante como a seguinte?

```
+-------------+---------------+------+------------+---------------+
|   CodItem   |   DataCompra  | Qtde |  ValorUnit |   ValorTotal  |
+-------------+---------------+------+------------+---------------+
|    Cod1     |    17/01/15   |  25  |    10,00   |     250,00    |  
|    Cod1     |    09/01/15   |  35  |    20,00   |     700,00    |
|    Cod1     |    11/01/15   |  50  |     5,00   |     250,00    |
|    Cod1     |    22/01/15   |  30  |    10,00   |     300,00    |
|    Cod2     |    19/01/15   |  10  |     5,00   |      50,00    |
|    Cod2     |    15/01/15   |  15  |    10,00   |     150,00    |
+-------------+---------------+------+------------+---------------+
```

O SQL da tabela resultante é o seguinte:

```
SELECT CodItem
      ,DataCompra
      ,'Qtde' = SUM(Qtde)
      ,ValorUnit
      ,ValorTotal

FROM...

WHERE DataCompra BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'

GROUP BY CodItem
      ,DataCompra
      ,ValorUnit
      ,ValorTotal
```

E meu resultado eu gostaria assim:

```
+-------------+---------------+------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|   CodItem   |   DataCompra  | Qtde |  ValorUnit |   ValorTotal  |  UltimoPreco  |
+-------------+---------------+------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|    Cod1     |    17/01/15   |  25  |    10,00   |     250,00    |     10,00     |
|    Cod1     |    09/01/15   |  35  |    20,00   |     700,00    |     10,00     |
|    Cod1     |    11/01/15   |  50  |     5,00   |     250,00    |     10,00     |
|    Cod1     |    22/01/15   |  30  |    10,00   |     300,00    |     10,00     |
|    Cod2     |    19/01/15   |  10  |     5,00   |      50,00    |      5,00     |
|    Cod2     |    15/01/15   |  15  |    10,00   |     150,00    |      5,00     |
+-------------+---------------+------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

De preferência (e apenas se possível) gostaria de saber como fazer isso no Crystal Reports. Mas no SQL também muito me ajudaria.

Answer (score 0):

Refazendo minha resposta , creio ter entendido mal antes

O que pode ser feito no sql é usar um subselect

```
SELECT CodItem ,DataCompra ,'Qtde' = SUM(Qtde) ,ValorUnit ,ValorTotal 
FROM tabela t1

WHERE DataCompra BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31' 

And DataCompra = (SELECT MAX(DataCompra)
                  From tabela t2
                  Where t2.CodItem = t1.CodItem)


GROUP BY CodItem ,DataCompra ,ValorUnit ,ValorTotal
```

Ou seja o subselect só trás a maior dada de compra de um "CodItem".

Comment: Mas isso resultaria uma tabela apenas com as maiores datas de compra, não? Eu preciso do resultado como uma nova coluna da Query. Vou editar a pergunta e adicionar como eu preciso do resultado.

Comment: Use o subselect como uma coluna, é só "mover" a solução

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018(v=sql.110).aspx dependendo do bd usar uma "analityc function" pode resolver , sei que Oracle e Sql Server tem.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um sub-select para recuperar o **UltimoPreco** por **CodItem**:

> SELECT CodItem ,DataCompra ,'Qtde' = SUM(Qtde) ,ValorUnit ,ValorTotal,  'UltimoPreco' = (SELECT TOP 1 S.ValorUnit FROM SUATABELA S WHERE S.CodItem = CodItem ORDER BY DataCompra) FROM SUATABELA WHERE DataCompra BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31' GROUP BY CodItem ,DataCompra ,ValorUnit ,ValorTotal